# .NET Core application communication with Active Directory having multiple domains, forests & trees

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I have been tasked to develop a .NET Core application. This application is going to communicate with `Active Directory` & `Azure AD`. For now, I am developing to retrieve information about OUs, Groups & Users from `Active Directory` only. The code is written pretty well but I am not an expert in Active Directory so I am here to get suggestions from experts regarding communication with AD using my application with a complex scenario.

**Edit:** Let rephrase my problem with simplicity. I have a .net core appliction integrated with Active Directory and will be integrated with Azure Active Directory soon. The application's main responsibility is, it will sync directory objects from AD and update them in SQL server. The application runs periodically and update if any information is changed in AD. Below are my requirements.

1. I want to create a Database schema which can hold the directory's configurations for both AD & AAD. Where the AD may have multiple domains and AAD may have multiple tenants.
2. I need to put each object into a DirectoryObjects table having identification of which directory, domain tenant it belongs to. So that when the app re-runs it looks into the right directory for the right domain and right tenants.

Please guide me I am really stuck here.

**Edit:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> > communication with AD using my application with a complex scenario.

I don't know the problem you are trying to solve, but have you considered configuring Azure AD Connect or Microsoft Identity Manager to do the multi-forest AD interaction/consolidation and focus your ASP.NET Core application on the data once it arrives in Azure AD?

I ask because there is a ton of complexity in retrieving, consolidating, and writing back users, groups, and devices from and to complex/heterogeneous on-premises Active Directory environments that AAD Connect and MIM are decades-old proven tech designed to handle. And they already are storing all of this information in a SQL database as they perform these operations. Finally, you can configure these tools (MIM more than AAD Connect) with custom sync rules to get this data transformed and stored in Azure AD.

If you have AD and Azure AD in the environment, it is almost a certainty that you already have AAD Connect and possibly MIM configured.

Just my .02.

Comment: Hi @Arvind, i have rephrased my question and made it as simple as i could. Please go through the edit section of main question above.

Comment: Hi @Imran, thanks for response and the rewording above. Are you able to share the highest level goal of this software development project? Without that knowledge, it sounds like you are trying to re-implement Azure AD Connect. Which could be an admirable goal by the way as it has a number of shortcomings. It would just help me to understand the overall outcome you are trying to achieve to provide guidance. Of course, Brian Desmond's Active Directory book is the authority and first place I would look for understanding the best way to interact with Active Directory.

Comment: Hi @Arvind, Thanks for your quick response. Please see my updated main question i have attached the HDL. Please suggest.

Comment: It looks like you want to store information from AD in a SQL database. And you want to store information from Azure AD in a SQL database. For what purposes? Backup and Restore? Something else?

Comment: That is the other application going to use the users information for provisioning documents. But i think there is no need to discuss that application here!

Comment: I just want to have database model that is going to handle both directories to use the same database model where we may have multiple domains or tenants.

Comment: I see. In that case. I would get the directories sync'd to an Azure AD tenant (or Azure AD tenants) and use Graph Delta Query to stay apprised of any newly created users that need provisioning. But Brian Desmond's book should be a great starting point if you want to track all AD data in a SQL database.